# How to set an error in Angular Custom Form Control

Tags: angular

I recently followed this tutorial [blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls) to make an Angular Custom Form Control.
Among other methods the tutorial says we really have to implement the `validate` method:

```
validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
  const quantity = control.value;
  if (quantity <= 0) {
    return {
      mustBePositive: {
        quantity
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I would like to add some custom validators to my component, but I didn't manage. In order to find out what is going wrong I modified the `validate` method to this:

```
public validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return { invalid: true };
}
```

In my understanding this method should always add an error every time the value changes. However, my form control is still valid. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the complete code to my custom component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {
    AbstractControl,
    ControlValueAccessor,
    NG_VALIDATORS,
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    NgModel,
    ValidationErrors,
    Validator,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-timespan',
    template: './timespan.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./timespan.component.sass'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            multi: true,
            useExisting: TimespanComponent,
        },
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            multi: true,
            useExisting: TimespanComponent,
        },
    ],
})
export class TimespanComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
    public minutes: number = 0;
    public hours: number = 0;
    @ViewChild('hoursInput') hoursInput: NgModel;
    @ViewChild('minutesInput') minutesInput: NgModel;

    private touched = false;
    public disabled = false;

    public get strings() {
        return this.translationService.strings.common.general;
    }

    public onMinutesChange(minutes: number) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.onTimeChange();
    }

    public onHoursChange(hours: number) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.onTimeChange();
    }

    public onTimeChange() {
        this.onChange(this.hours * 60 + this.minutes);
    }

    /**
     All the methods below are required for formControl:
     */
    // quantity is required for formControl
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    private onChange = quantity => {};
    private onTouched = () => {};

    public writeValue(quantity: number) {
        if (this.minutes < 0 || this.minutes > 59) {
        }
        this.minutes = quantity ? quantity % 60 : null;
        this.hours = quantity ? (quantity - this.minutes) / 60 : null;
    }

    public registerOnChange(onChange: (arg0: number) => void) {
        this.onChange = onChange;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(onTouched: () => void) {
        this.onTouched = onTouched;
    }

    public markAsTouched() {
        if (!this.touched) {
            this.onTouched();
            this.touched = true;
        }
    }

    public setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
        this.disabled = disabled;
    }

    public validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        return { invalid: true };
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="flex">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" (click)="this.markAsTouched()">
        <mat-label>
            {{ this.hours === 1 ? strings.hour() : strings.hours() }}
        </mat-label>
        <input
            matInput
            type="number"
            min="0"
            max="24"
            [ngModel]="hours"
            (ngModelChange)="onHoursChange($event)"
            #hoursInput="ngModel"
            [disabled]="disabled"
        />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>
            {{ this.minutes === 1 ? strings.minute() : strings.minutes() }}
        </mat-label>
        <input
            matInput
            type="number"
            min="0"
            max="59"
            [ngModel]="minutes"
            (ngModelChange)="onMinutesChange($event)"
            #minutesInput="ngModel"
            [disabled]="disabled"
        />
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I'm using Angular 15.